# 2 column layout in Rmarkdown with tabset

Tags: css, r, tabs, r-markdown

I am trying a 2 column layout using CSS to divide the sapce in 2 halfs. However the {.tabset} command is not working. I have tried multiple combinations but no help.

```
---
title: "2 Column layout with tabs"
output:
  html_document:
    css: style.css
---

<div class = "col-leftmid">

# A {.tabset}

## abc

</div>

<div class = "col-rightmid">

# B {.tabset}

## xyz

</div>
```

here is style.css content for column divide used

```
.col-leftmid{
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: left;
}

.col-rightmid{
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the solution and its working for now. I only needed to mention the "col-leftmid"/"col-rightmid" beside the tabset call.

```
---
title: "2 Column layout with tabs"
output:
  html_document:
    css: style.css
---

# A {.tabset .col-leftmid}

## abc


# B {.tabset .col-rightmid}

## xyz

## mno
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI it works for dropdown tabs too :

```
# A {.tabset .col-leftmid}

## abc


# B {.tabset .col-rightmid .tabset-dropdown}

## xyz

## mno
```